# Evitar que un MsgBox se repita 2 veces en VBA

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-forms, vba

No se por que razon se duplica 2 veces mi MsgBox, se supone que cuando esten los espacios en blanco envie un mensaje que avise que estan en blanco, todo esto al presionar un radio button, la primera vez funciona, pero en la segunda, la tercera ya muestra el mensaje 2 veces. dejo el codigo:

```
 Function validarBlancos(ByVal textoUno As String, ByVal textoDos As String) As Boolean

    Return String.IsNullOrEmpty(textoUno) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(textoDos)

End Function
```

y en el siguiente codigo llamo a la function:

```
Private Sub rbtnSumar_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbtnSumar.CheckedChanged

    MsgBox("bandera suma")
    If Not validarBlancos(txtNumeroUno.Text.Trim, txtNumeroDos.Text.Trim) Then
        numeroUno = Integer.Parse(txtNumeroUno.Text)
        numeroDos = Integer.Parse(txtNumeroDos.Text)
        If rbtnSumar.Checked = True Then
            txtResultado.Text = numeroUno + numeroDos
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Espacio en blanco... Reintente", vbExclamation, "Espacio en blanco,suma")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub rbtnRestar_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbtnRestar.CheckedChanged

    MsgBox("bandera resta")
    If Not validarBlancos(txtNumeroUno.Text.Trim, txtNumeroDos.Text.Trim) Then
        numeroUno = Integer.Parse(txtNumeroUno.Text)
        numeroDos = Integer.Parse(txtNumeroDos.Text)
        If rbtnRestar.Checked = True Then
            txtResultado.Text = numeroUno - numeroDos
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Espacio en blanco... Reintente",, "Espacio en blanco,resta")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub rbtnMultiplicar_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbtnMultiplicar.CheckedChanged

    MsgBox("bandera multi")
    If Not validarBlancos(txtNumeroUno.Text.Trim, txtNumeroDos.Text.Trim) Then
        numeroUno = Integer.Parse(txtNumeroUno.Text)
        numeroDos = Integer.Parse(txtNumeroDos.Text)
        If rbtnMultiplicar.Checked = True Then
            txtResultado.Text = numeroUno * numeroDos
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Espacio en blanco... Reintente",, "Espacio en blanco,multi")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub rbtnDividir_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbtnDividir.CheckedChanged

    MsgBox("bandera dividir")
    If Not validarBlancos(txtNumeroUno.Text.Trim, txtNumeroDos.Text.Trim) Then
        numeroUno = Integer.Parse(txtNumeroUno.Text)
        numeroDos = Integer.Parse(txtNumeroDos.Text)
        If rbtnDividir.Checked = True Then
            If numeroDos = 0 Then
                MsgBox("No puede dividir por 0, Reintente")
                txtNumeroDos.Clear()
            Else
                txtResultado.Text = numeroUno / numeroDos
            End If
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Espacio en blanco... Reintente",, "Espacio en blanco,dividir")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Puedes comprobar que no se esté llamando dos veces `rbtnSumar_CheckedChanged` creo que el problema está en que se llama dos veces al evento. Pon un `MsgBox`delante del `If Not validarBlancos...` a ver que tal.

Comment: puse el todo el codigo que contiene los radiobutton, puse el MsgBox y aparece el anterior cada ves que le hago click a otro, si clickeo primero sumar o cualquier otro, aparece una sola vez el MsgBox, pero al clickearle a cualquier otro, aparece los mensajes del anterior y despues del que clickeo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algunas consideraciones en su código a tomar en cuenta para mejorar y evitar estos incovenientes

1. Sería mejor que la comprobación de dos variables la realizará utilizando el operador lógico [OR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-pe/library/06s37a7f.aspx)
2. La forma más óptima y adecuada de verificar variables vacías y además `null` es con el método [IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. Tener en cuenta usar el método [Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.trim(v=vs.110).aspx) para eliminar espacios en blanco de los extremos de la cadena
4. Cuando se inserta un método que retorna un valor `booleano` en un `if`, no es necesario la validación `=True` sin eso ya se sobreentiende que es verificará que sea `True` si no podría usar el operador de negación [Not](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-pe/library/2cwcswt4.aspx) (Opcional)
5. El Mensaje que coloca en su método debería ir en el `else` de su comprobación en el método `CheckedChanged`
6. Su método no retorna ningún valor `booleano` **(as Boolean)** como especifica la documentación https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-PE/library/6xxtk8kx.aspx

Su código quedaría así.

```
/* Funcion con retorno Booleano (as Boolean)-> Tipo retorno */
Function validarBlancos(ByVal textoUno As String, ByVal textoDos As String) As Boolean
    /* Un solo return , evitamos el if else */
    Return String.IsNullOrEmpty(textoUno) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(textoDos)
End Function




Private Sub rbtnSumar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbtnSumar.CheckedChanged
    /* Esto sería igual a decir , si no hay(Not) espacios en blanco */
    If Not validarBlancos(txtNumeroUno.Text.Trim, txtNumeroDos.Text.Trim) Then
        numeroUno = Integer.Parse(txtNumeroUno.Text)
        numeroDos = Integer.Parse(txtNumeroDos.Text)
        If rbtnSumar.Checked = True Then
            txtResultado.Text = numeroUno + numeroDos
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Espacio en blanco... Reintente")
    End If
End Sub
```

**Update**

El problema de los dos mensajes radica en que cuando un `RadioButton1.Checked = True` y cambias al `RadioButton2.Checked = True` el `RadioButton1.Checked = False` se lanza el evento `CheckedChanged` de los dos. es por eso que lanza los dos `else` (Dos mensajes)

Una solución rápida sería el código añadirlo al evento `Click` de los `Checkbox` 
Otra sería verificar si esta `Checked=True` el `CheckBox`

```
 Private Sub rbtnSumar_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    If rbtnSumar.Checked = True Then
        If Not validarBlancos(txtNumeroUno.Text.Trim, txtNumeroDos.Text.Trim) Then
             numeroUno = Integer.Parse(txtNumeroUno.Text)
              numeroDos = Integer.Parse(txtNumeroDos.Text)
             If rbtnMultiplicar.Checked = True Then
              txtResultado.Text = numeroUno * numeroDos
             End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Espacio en blanco... Reintente", vbExclamation, "Espacio en blanco,suma")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Exelentes acotaciones para tener encuenta, pero el msgbox sigue apareciendo 2 veces.

Comment: los mismos cambio que me sugirió, otra cosa que me di cuenta recien, le puse titulos a los MsgBox, y cuando se repite, se repite el del radiobutton anteriormente presionado y luego el que presione. no se que puede ser.

Comment: Podría usar el enlace editar para modificar como está su código ahora, es raro si siguió mis consejos no debería tener problemas

Comment: listo, ahora esta editado

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta. espero te ayude

Comment: Funciona!, muchas gracias por los concejos y por ayudarme!

Comment: Un Gusto para mi, a seguir. si tienes dudas o problemas no olvides que podemos ayudarte.